# Getting error with firebase_messaging plugin

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm adding `firebase_messaging` plugin to my project, the previous version had `firebase_messaging` and was working fine. I'm shifting my project from using `flutter_webview_plugin` to using `webview_flutter`, so I changed my code accordingly but I started getting errors. I created new project and the same error is thrown, but when I removed `firebase_messaging` it started working.

This is the error:-

```
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/55.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/58.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/61.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/64.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/67.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/70.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/76.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/79.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/82.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/85.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/88.jar, /Users/KiranMenon/Desktop/tydy_mobile/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/91.jar
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See **************** for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11113) on github about that. Also, if you are using the latest plugins you should migrate your project to be compatible with [AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility). And make sure your `compileSdkVersion` is compatible with those plugins. ps: `flutter clean` it after you try those things.